# How to use parameters in report when using SSRS matrix and table wizard

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, olap-cube, reportbuilder3.0

I would like my users to be able to create their own quick and easy reports from a cube on the fly, and that is most simply done using the "Table or Matrix Wizard" in Report Builder.

However they need to filter by date--and it wont work.

I have tried:

1) Creating a dataset with parameters imbedded. When you run the report, it asks for a parameter but there are no values in the drop down -- and an analysis of the "Parameter Properties" shows no available values. (Even though I chose values when creating the dataset)

2)Creating two datasets, one with all the data and one with only the date field. However the matrix wizard will not allow you to use 2 datasets.

Is there any simple way to add a filter to the report so that my users can just load a dataset/two and then use the Matrix wizard?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the user running the report needs to define a date parameter, they need to create a date parameter with the same name as the parameter in the stored procedure that is called by the report. They should then set the Data Type to Date/Time, and make sure the parameter is visible.

[image]

When the user runs the report, they will be able to use the calendar feature to pass the date value to the report procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your response !I didn't want to teach them about parameters, I wanted it to be extremely quick and easy. Only one wizard-- Instead I just created an empty shared report with two datasets and then can run the wizard from there.

Comment: I hope they like this solution.